# Number of redirects hit maximum amount | gconnect() in gtrendsR package

Tags: r, api, connection, gtrendsr

I am trying to get data using gtrendsR package. But I am stuck at the connection.

```
library('gtrendsR')
session <- gconnect("username@gmail.com", "mypass")
```

I know google recognize my email address and my password, but I think the problem is with R because I am getting the following error:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    Number of redirects
>   hit maximum amount

However, I am not sure. Has anyone encountered this problem before and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library('gtrendsR')
session <- gconnect("username@gmail.com", "mypass")
```

It's a server side problem. Wait for the package update