# "Number of redirects hit maximum amount" issue

Tags: r, curl, web-scraping

I am training on web scraping (using R and rvest, curl package) and I often get the same error and the scraping stops after that.
I would like to understand this error:

> "Number of redirects hit maximum amount"

What does it really mean?
Anyways to work around that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not super helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766863/number-of-redirects-hit-maximum-amount-gconnect-in-gtrendsr-package), but might be the only solution. Are youre packages up to date?

Comment: I saw this answer yes not the most helpful ! Yes they are up to date. I am thinking my ip might temporarily be blocked from the website, could that be possible ? How could I check that ?

Comment: If you scraped too much or accessed their website too often in a certain period of time, they might have blocked you. Definily possible and reasonable. You can check that if you ping the website for example?